# Problem clicking the button Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[image: HTML CODE]

I tried this method that works perfectly for other buttons (different class) on the same web page but not this specific button, I also tried using div class:

```
xpathoo = '//button[@class="ncss-brand pt2-sm pr5-sm pb2-sm pl5-sm ncss-btn-accent continueOrderReviewBtn mod-button-width ncss-brand\
        pt3-sm prl5-sm pb3-sm pt2-lg pb2-lg d-sm-b d-md-ib u-uppercase u-rounded fs14-sm"]' 
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathoo).click()
```

Comment: that class value seems that may change(when you resize the screen for example), what if you use the value of data-attr? something like `//button[@data-attr='continueToOrderReviewBtn']`

Answer (score 0):

The element with text as **PASSA ALLA VERIFICA DELL** is a dynamic element so click on it you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.continueOrderReviewBtn[data-attr='continueToOrderReviewBtn']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-attr='continueToOrderReviewBtn' and contains(., 'PASSA ALLA VERIFICA DELL')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```